# Ошибка чтения по айди из базы данных

Tags: python, sqlite

Хочу получить из базы имя пользователя по айди, но не находит

```py
c.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=0')
print(c.fetchall())
```

Вывод:

```
[]
```

При этом бд:
[image]

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Как создавалась БД?

Comment: sqlite, строчка с айди 1 через питон, с нулем - через приложение

Comment: или интересует сам процесс коннекта? уточню, не работает именно с WHERE id = 0, без работает на ура

Comment: Возможно, `id` имеет строковый тип.

Comment: Нужен полный код коннекта к бд и описание структуры таблицы.

Comment: уже решил, спасибо Михаилу

Answer (score -2):

> уточню, не работает именно с WHERE id = 0, без работает на ура

Поле *id*, скорее всего, объявлено как индекс таблицы. А следовательно - как NOT NULL. Как-то так:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
```

Вы мне другое объясните - как Вы умудрились засунуть в таблицу строку с нулевым *id* ?!